# Box plots, plots in octave

Tags: plot, statistics, octave, boxplot

I'm new to Octave, so there are many confusing things for me, and I've never done computer programming before so most of the language is also confusing.

I have sets of data c_o, m_o, y_o, k_o as 144 x 1 matrices (column vectors?)

**Box plots**

Using examples I found online, I wrote this:

```
 axis ([0,5]);
 boxplot (c_o, m_o, y_o, k_o);
 set(gca (), "xtick", [1,2,3,4], "xticklabel", {"cyan", "magenta", "yellow", "key"});
```

However, it results in an error

```
Boxplot.m: grouping vector may only be passed as second arg
```

I have no idea what this means.

**Plots**

I'm trying to figure out how to plot multiple data sets with different colors.

For example,

```
figure (1); plot (c_o , "c");
```

works perfectly fine.

However, I'd like to remove the horizontal axis, change the horizontal axis from [0,200] to [0,150] , and plot multiple sets of data on the same plot (not multiple plots in the same figure, but the different data on the same set of axis). I haven't been able to find out how, though.

For the record, I do know that there are probably other programming languages more suited for statistical analysis; it just so happens that my first use of this happened to be statistical in nature.

Comment: It helps to read [the documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/boxplot.html). `boxplot` accepts only one data input argument. Try `boxplot({c_o, m_o, y_o, k_o})` -- this creates a cell array with your 4 data sets, passing them together as a single argument.

Comment: Also, please keep each question to a single question. The Q&A style of this site requires that. See [tour] and [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! I did read that, but I must have missed the brackets in Demonstration 1. Small details.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I can see how a person unfamiliar with the language would have to jump through a few hoops to reach that conclusion; your answer is useful, I'd consider turning it into a proper answer and have OP accept it :)